# How to get rid of line under logo html css bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am creating a website for someone and when I place the logo it has a line of the background color under it. It is pretty frustrating and it ruins the design so does anyone know how to get rid of it? I need to know a solid solution so I know how to do it in the future, so while it might work I need something that isn't crazy and I need it to be somewhat concise.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
<title>Pressure Pros</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Kanit|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()){

});
</script>

<style>

.navbar-brand{
 font-size: 50px;
 color:white;
 font-family:'Lobster';
 height: 100%;
}

a{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Abel';
 font-size: 30px;
}

p{
 font-family: 'Kanit';
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar{
  padding-top:20px;
}

#alone{
 background-image: url(/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/alone.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.navbar-header{
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

#three{
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

#box-wrapper{
  background-image: url(/Users/adk6332/Desktop/Bootstrap/images/imagethree.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#logo{
padding:0px;
}

.middleimage{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:275px;
  left: 485px;
  color: white;
  font-family:'Abel';
}

.bottomimage{
 font-size: 60px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top:175px;
 left: 185px;
 color: black;
 font-family:'Abel';
}

#model{
  margin: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#407EC1;">
 <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="/Users/alecklem/Desktop/project1/media/pp_logo_3.png" style="height:80px; width: 217px;" id="logo"></a>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand "href="#">Pressure </a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
     <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="fleet.html">Fleet Washing</a></li>
         <li><a href="residential.html">Residential Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="commercial.html">Commercial Service</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
<div class="jumbotron" id="box-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
        <div class="text-uppercase middleimage">
          <h1>Pressure Pros</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <br>
  <br>
<div class="container">
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboru

</p>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="jumbotron" id="alone">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="text-uppercase bottomimage">
    <h1> Miracle Model of the Month </h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laboru
 </p>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEiWa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your height logo more than 80px
Example:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="/Users/alecklem/Desktop/project1/media/pp_logo_3.png" style="height:90px; width: 217px;" id="logo"></a>
```

Comment: If I add any more than the whole nav bar increases height and the bar stays there.

Comment: the problem is in your bootstrap file. First step, You can download your bootstrap css: maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.cs‌​s. And then edit in .navbar-fixed-top{top:0;border-width:0 0 1px}, to .navbar-fixed-top{top:0;border-width:0 0 0px}.
After that, you can save bootstrap file in local, and dont forget to set your css call,
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR FILE LOCATION">

Answer (score 0):

Set white as a background for the `<img>` and set it to `display: block` if needed. Then check if it needs more height than 80px in order to cover navbar's blue background.

### Update

I just saw that you have a transparent bottom border on on `navbar`. Just add a new CSS rule to your .navbar-fixed-top class, like this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it still didn't work. Again it just made the whole navbar taller and the bar is still there.